# Display second Y axis using dygraph

Tags: r, dygraphs

Trying to have two Y axis with different scales. The second Y axis scale doesn't show and the data plotted almost entirely off screen. This is what I have:

```
dygraph(bmsp1, main = "Black MO SP")%>%
dyAxis("y", label = "Depth (m) ", valueRange = c(0, 1.0))%>%
dyAxis("y2", label = "Temp (c) ", valueRange = c(0, 25.0))
```

[Plot of depth and temp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YadZ8.jpg)

I also tried this but get the error:

```
dygraph(bmsp1, main = "Black MO SP")%>%
+     dyAxis("y", label = "Depth (m) ", valueRange = c(0, 1.0))%>%
+     dyAxis("y2", label = "Temp (c) ", valueRange = c(0, 25.0))%>%
+     dyAxis("Temp", axis('y2'))
```

Error in dyAxis(., "Temp", axis("y2"))

I haven't figured out how to add the data using the dput() (file size too large). Here is snapshot from head()

```
> head(bmsp1)
                Depth Temp (c)
2015-09-30 09:00:00 0.003   21.378
2015-09-30 09:15:00 0.228   17.475
2015-09-30 09:30:00 0.228   17.475
2015-09-30 09:45:00 0.224   17.475
2015-09-30 10:00:00 0.225   17.475
2015-09-30 10:15:00 0.224   17.475
```

Here is dput() for 75 rows (I think).

```
> dput(head(bmsp1, 75))
structure(c(0.003, 0.228, 0.228, 0.224, 0.225, 0.224, 0.227, 
0.226, 0.23, 0.218, 0.223, 0.224, 0.229, 0.226, 0.226, 0.222, 
0.228, 0.233, 0.233, 0.233, 0.232, 0.225, 0.217, 0.209, 0.204, 
0.212, 0.222, 0.212, 0.23, 0.224, 0.216, 0.228, 0.231, 0.23, 
0.223, 0.223, 0.232, 0.224, 0.223, 0.225, 0.224, 0.219, 0.215, 
0.211, 0.211, 0.215, 0.221, 0.213, 0.216, 0.222, 0.222, 0.224, 
0.217, 0.212, 0.214, 0.212, 0.209, 0.21, 0.207, 0.207, 0.206, 
0.205, 0.204, 0.204, 0.203, 0.198, 0.197, 0.199, 0.194, 0.184, 
0.179, 0.189, 0.195, 0.192, 0.19, 21.378, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 
17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 
17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 
17.475, 17.57, 17.57, 17.57, 17.57, 17.57, 17.475, 17.57, 17.475, 
17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 17.475, 
17.475, 17.379, 17.379, 17.379, 17.379, 17.379, 17.379, 17.379, 
17.379, 17.284, 17.284, 17.284, 17.284, 17.284, 17.284, 17.189, 
17.189, 17.189, 17.189, 17.094, 17.094, 17.094, 17.094, 16.999, 
16.999, 16.999, 16.999, 16.903, 16.903, 16.903, 16.903, 16.903, 
16.808, 16.808, 16.808, 16.808, 16.713, 16.713), .indexTZ = "UTC",     .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(1443603600, 1443604500, 1443605400, 
1443606300, 1443607200, 1443608100, 1443609000, 1443609900, 1443610800, 
1443611700, 1443612600, 1443613500, 1443614400, 1443615300, 1443616200, 
1443617100, 1443618000, 1443618900, 1443619800, 1443620700, 1443621600, 
1443622500, 1443623400, 1443624300, 1443625200, 1443626100, 1443627000, 
1443627900, 1443628800, 1443629700, 1443630600, 1443631500, 1443632400, 
1443633300, 1443634200, 1443635100, 1443636000, 1443636900, 1443637800, 
1443638700, 1443639600, 1443640500, 1443641400, 1443642300, 1443643200, 
1443644100, 1443645000, 1443645900, 1443646800, 1443647700, 1443648600, 
1443649500, 1443650400, 1443651300, 1443652200, 1443653100, 1443654000, 
1443654900, 1443655800, 1443656700, 1443657600, 1443658500, 1443659400, 
1443660300, 1443661200, 1443662100, 1443663000, 1443663900, 1443664800, 
1443665700, 1443666600, 1443667500, 1443668400, 1443669300, 1443670200
), tzone = "UTC", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), .Dim = c(75L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Depth", "Temp")))
```

Comment: can you add your data (using dput()) to your post?

Comment: can you just relabel Temp (c) with something like Temp_c and see if it works

Comment: is bmsp1 a timeseries? what is str(bmsp1)

Comment: I changed the name to Temp and temp_c and get same result.

Comment: > str(bmsp1)
An ‘xts’ object on 2015-09-30 09:00:00/2016-02-02 09:45:00 containing:
  Data: num [1:12004, 1:2] 0.003 0.228 0.228 0.224 0.225 0.224 0.227 0.226 0.23 0.218 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "Depth" "Temp"
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL

Comment: it's hard to test when you don't have access to the data...in your dyAxis("Temp", axis('y2')); in your previous line the label is Temp (c); so try dyAxis("Temp (c)", axis('y2')); you need to have the same label

Comment: I don't mind sending the data. Can attach a .txt file here?

Comment: try my previous comment

Comment: Good catch but that still didn't work.

Comment: and this should be dySeries("Temp (c)", axis('y2')) not dyAxis("Temp (c)", axis('y2'))

Comment: When ran that way I get:   Error in axis("y2") : plot.new has not been called yet

Comment: you will have to make your post reproducible. No data, we can't reproduce your error.

Comment: @MLavoie - I added some dput() data to original post above. I hope that works. And thanks for being patient with me (obvious newb).

Comment: strangely this work dygraph(bmsp1) %>%
    dySeries("Depth", axis = 'y2')

Comment: That is strange. I still would like it plotted with depth on left as the primary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this will work. there was "=" missing in your last line.

```
dygraph(bmsp1, main = "Black MO SP")%>%
         dyAxis("y", label = "Depth", valueRange = c(0, 1.0), independentTicks = TRUE)%>%
         dyAxis("y2", label = "Temp ", valueRange = c(0, 25.0), independentTicks = TRUE) %>%
         dySeries("Temp", axis=('y2'))
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you very much.